# How can I find an index of list in function python

Tags: python, list, function, indexing

I make many functions in my project and at the one function I need to find the index of one list for another list, but it doesn't perform and shows an error.

```
def name():
    Name = []    
    while True:
        Name.append(input('<Department Electricity,District 1,Tehran>\n Hello dear customer\n enter your name: '))
        if input('press s to stop: ') == 's':
            break
    return Name

def expense(get_name):
    expense = []
    for x in get_name:
       expense.append(int(input(f' dear {x} insert your monthly electricity expense: ')))
    return expense

def average(Expense):
    avg = sum(Expense) / len(Expense)
    return avg

def result(name, expense, average):   
    for x in expense:        
        if x > average:
            index = expense.index[x]         
            print(name[index], 'is high expense')
     
Name = name()
Expense = expense(Name)
result(Name, Expense, average(Expense))
```

Comment: What error does it show?

Comment: How about using `for index, x in emumerate(expense):`?

Comment: And don't overload names. `expense` is both, the name of a function and a parameter to result.

Comment: Instead of expense.index[x], it looks like you want to use expense.index(x)

Comment: Take a look at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to use for each loop in 'result' function.
Make sure you are able to work with regular for loop as well.

```
def result(name, expense, average):   
    for i in range(len(expense)):        
        if expense[i] > average:        
            print(name[i], 'is high expense')
```